# How to find which version of R is required for a package

Tags: r, package, version, versioning

I have `R` version `3.0.1` however this is too recent it seems to install the package [`darch`](http://cran.um.ac.ir/web/packages/darch/index.html). Therefore I would like to know how to find out what version of `R` I need to have installed in order to use this package?

Comment: `darch` should work with the latest version of R. The checks seem to be ok as seen [here](http://cran.um.ac.ir/web/checks/check_results_darch.html).

Comment: @Ramnath How do you find the minimum version that will work with this package (or any other package for that matter)?

Comment: @Ramnath I have 3.0.1 and it says it's not available for this version.

Answer (score 1):

Any dependencies for a package are normally listed in the DESCRIPTION file in the package, which in turn appears on the CRAN webpage for the package.  In your case, the darch package page on [CRAN](http://cran.um.ac.ir/web/packages/darch/index.html) lists the following in the "Depends" field:

```
Depends:    methods, log4r, ff
```

That is, the author listed his project as working for all versions of R.  For an example of a package with an explicit R version requirement, you can see my package [choroplethr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/choroplethr/index.html).  It lists the following under "Depends":

```
Depends:    R (≥ 3.0.0)
```

I received a lot of bug reports from people running R version 2.15, so I made 3.0.0 a minimum requirement.

Note that it would be unusual for CRAN to list a package which does not work with the latest version of R.  You would have to check their policies about that - it might not even be permitted.

I think that your next step is to contact the maintainer of the package.  Each package listed on CRAN is required to list a maintainer and their email address.  In my experience, I have normally received prompt replies when I've had technical problems using someone's package.  In the case of darch this is listed as:

```
Maintainer: Martin Drees <mdrees at stud.fh-dortmund.de>
```